# Prove that : $\gcd ( a.P(X) + b.Q(X), cP(X) + dQ(X) ) = \gcd ( P(X), Q(X) )$

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory

Let  $P(X)$  and  $Q(X)$  be two polynomials in  $R[X].$  Let  $a, b, c, d$  be four real numbers such that      $ad – bc  ≠  0$.                                                                                                                                                                             Prove that :
$$\gcd(aP(X) + bQ(X), cP(X) + dQ(X))= \gcd (P(X), Q(X)).$$

Can someone help me to resolve this ? I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Essentially the same as in the dupe since the determinant is a unit (invertible) in $\Bbb R$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$r(x)= \gcd ( a.P(X) + b.Q(X),    cP(X) + dQ(X) )$$ and $$s(x)    =     \gcd ( P(X), Q(X) ).$$

Since $P=sP'$ and $Q= sQ'$ we have $$aP+bQ = s(aP'+bQ')$$ and $$cP+dQ = s(cP'+dQ')$$ which means that $s\mid aP+bQ$ and $s\mid cP+dQ$ so $\boxed{s\mid r}$.

---

Vice versa, we prove $r\mid s$ (and so $s=r$): $$r\mid c(aP+bQ)-a(cP+dQ) = (cb-ad)Q $$

so $r\mid Q$ and the same way we get $r\mid P$ so $\boxed{r\mid s}$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\tilde P(X)=aP(X) + bQ(X)$ and $\tilde Q(X)=cP(X) + dQ(X)$. Then
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\tilde P(X) \\ \tilde Q(X) 
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\ c & d
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
P(X) \\ Q(X) 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and so
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
P(X) \\ Q(X) 
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\ c & d
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{pmatrix}
\tilde P(X) \\ \tilde Q(X) 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
because $ad – bc \ne 0$.
Therefore 
$\gcd(\tilde P(X,\tilde Q(X))$ divides $\gcd (P(X), Q(X))$.